# Append data first then group or group first the append

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, with the exact same format. Since each table has the date column(the date used to create the table), group first or append first will not make any difference to the result.

I use two queries to test:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT 
 TXN,CONT,ReportingDate,sum(AMT) AS TOT
  FROM Table1
  GROUP BY TXN,CONT,ReportingDate
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 
 TXN,CONT,ReportingDate,sum(AMT) AS TOT
  FROM Table2
  GROUP BY TXN,CONT,ReportingDate)
  TEST

SELECT TXN, CONT,Reportingdate,sum(AMT)
from
(
SELECT 
 TXN,CONT,AMT,ReportingDate
  FROM Table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
 TXN,CONT,AMT,ReportingDate
  FROM Table2
  )
  test
  GROUP BY
  TXN,CONT,Reportingdate
```

(22596 row(s) affected)

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 156 ms,  elapsed time = 2582 ms.

(22596 row(s) affected)

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 125 ms,  elapsed time = 2337 ms.

The statistics do not show a lot of difference. The timings change a few every time I run the queries.

The Execution plan 
[image]

Which one will be faster? I just list one result here. I run these two queries for 10 times, 7 out of which show query 1 is faster.

The reportingdate column will be totally different in the two tables, so there will be no duplicate result for query 1. For example, the reportingdate in table 1 is a column of 10/28/2015s, and the reportingdate in table 2 are 10/29/2015s.

Thanks

Comment: Suggestions about what?  What is your question?  I should note that the two queries are different.  The first can return duplicate combinations of `TXN, CONT, ReportingDate`, but the second cannot.

Answer (score 1):

Typically when decided which version of a SQL statement I want to use I consider the following:

1. Will they both return the same results?  As mentioned by Gordon in the comment, conceptually the first would return a row duplicated in both tables as separate rows whereas the second would group them together and you would see the sum of both of them.
2. Performance difference.  Not much performance difference here, but the second one does seem to be faster (which makes sense as the DBMS is able to get all the rows and then sum once rather than get some rows, sum, then get some more rows, and sum)
3. Readability/maintainability.  In your opinion, when someone is debugging this later on, would they rather test the inner statements with or without a grouping statement?  Really your call on this one.

Comment: 1. I edited my question. The reporting date column in two tables will be different, so the two queries will return the same result. 2. This time, query 2 is faster. But most of the times, query 1 will be faster. I just list one result here. 3. This will be just me doing the maintenance. I just want to test the performance issue, since pulling data from the data warehouse is just the first step and the data will be quite big.

Comment: Do you have the option of running this against a production-sized data set?  There are no glaring issues with either of your SQL statements, they both should perform well.  So sadly at this point there's really no better way to tell which is better than actually production performance.  One other thing, rerunning the same code will get faster because the database starts caching things, so the first run of each SQL is the best indicator of actual performance.

Comment: I will get the real data next week and then test it. When I started learning SQL, I was told to run the query twice and check the second time's result. I am guessing it is intended to let the cache work, because the query will be run multiple times in real life.

Comment: Good point, it really depends on how often the query is run to know whether to care more about the first run or second.